# Global dimension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, global-dimension

1. What is the global dimension of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/t\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the local ring, $p$ prime and $p \mid t$?
2. What is the global dimension of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three results which in principle reduce the computation of global dimension to that of Krull dimension:

a) The global dimension  of a noetherian ring $A$  is the supremum of the global dimension at its localizations at its maximal ideals: $ \text {gldim} A=\text {sup}_{\mathfrak m \in\text {Specmax }A}        \;  \text {gldim} {A_\mathfrak m }  $
  b) For a regular noetherian local ring the global dimension equals the Krull dimension: $  \text {gldim} A=\text {dim} A$
 c) For a non-regular local noetherian ring $  \text {gldim} A=\infty$

Your questions are then immediately solved (if you notice that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/t\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is of the form $\mathbb Z/(n))$:$$\quad  \text {gldim} \: \mathbb Z_{(p)}=1$$and$$ \quad \text {gldim} \;\mathbb Z/(n)=0 \quad\text {or}\quad\text {gldim} \;\mathbb Z/(n)=\infty$$ according as $n$ is square-free or not.